# enviar información de javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Ttengo un formulario PHP y unos campos con botones que agregar campos de testo y un boton para adjuntar un archivo esto lo hago en javascript lo que no se es como regresar el contenido de mi formulario de javascript a php para guardar los datos en mi BD en MYSQL

este es mi botón agregar

```html
                       <span class="section">¿Con qué?</span>
                        <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Debemos declarar que infraestructura utilizamos para realizar las actividades del proceso.<span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="main">
                            <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir Elemento" class="bt" />
                            <input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Eliminar Elemento" class="bt" />
                            <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="bt" /><br />

                        </div>
                        </div>
```

este es la función en javascript para agregar campos

```js
//agregar campos con que
$(document).ready(function() {
var iCnt = 0;
 
// Crear un elemento div añadiendo estilos CSS
var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
padding: '1px', margin: '70px', width: '950px', border: '1px dashed'
});$('#btAdd').click(function() {
if (iCnt <= 19) {
 
iCnt = iCnt + 1;
 
// Añadir caja de texto.
$(container).append('<div class="item form-group">\n\
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Con Que?<span class="required">*</span></label>\n\
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><input type=text class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Cual es tu Salida" required="required" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'value="¿Con qué?' + iCnt + '" />\n\Seleccione Archivo:<INPUT type="file" name="archivo" size="30" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'value="¿Con qué?' + iCnt + '"></div></div>');

if (iCnt == 1) {
 
var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
//$(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' +
//'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');
 
}
 
$('#main').after(container, divSubmit);
}
else { //se establece un limite para añadir elementos, 20 es el limite
 
$(container).append('<label>Limite Alcanzado</label>');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable');
$('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 
}
});
 
$('#btRemove').click(function() { // Elimina un elemento por click
if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; }
 
if (iCnt == 0) { $(container).empty();
 
$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove();
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt')
 
}
});
 
$('#btRemoveAll').click(function() { // Elimina todos los elementos del contenedor
 
$(container).empty();
$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0;
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt');
 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez pase por el mismo problema...
mi solución fue, cada vez que agregaba un nuevo elemento, aumentar el contador en el name del imput, ejemplo

```
<INPUT type="file" name="archivo'+ iCnt +'" size="30" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +'value="¿Con qué?' + iCnt + '">
```

utilizando el mismo contador que ya tienes.. se aumenta el contador al name, archivo1, archivo2, archivo3.... ya cuando se termine de agregar los inputs mandas ese contador y con eso ya sabes cuantos inputs tienes para llamar en el php con un for